# how to prove that $f_n(x)=e^{-nx^2+x}$ is Lebesgue integrable for all $n\geq 1$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have tried using this definition: $$ f  \text{ integrable (measureable)} \Leftrightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)| d\mu < \infty$$

We know that $f$ is measurable because it is a continuous function.

I think that I need to bound $f_n(x)$ with an integrable function... but I don't know which one I should choose.

I have done the following: $$|f_n(x)|= e^{-nx^2+x} =e^{-nx^2}e^{x} \leq e^{-x^2}e^x\leq h(x), \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$
$$h(x)=\begin{cases}
   e^{-x^2},& x \leq 0\\
    ???????& x>0
    \end{cases} $$
Thank you

Comment: For the case when $x>0$, can you define $h(x)$ to be $e^{x}$ which is a Riemann integrable function and hence is also Lebesgue Integrable? In fact in either case, you could define $h(x)$ by $e^{x}$ which will be the upper bound of each $f_{n}(x)$.

Comment: but $\int_0^{\infty}e^x dx=+\infty$, and I need a finite integral so that I can use the definition I have written...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int e^{-x^{2}+x}dx=e^{1/4}\int e^{-(x-\frac1  2)^{2}}dx=e^{1/4}\int e^{-y^{2}}dy=e^{1/4}\sqrt {\pi}$

[$\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-y^{2}} dy=\sqrt {\pi}$. This is a standard result in Calculus and it is proved by going to polar coordinates].